# React iterate over object from json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

class News extends React.Component {
  render () {
    var news = [];
    this.props.news.forEach(function(el, i){
        news.push(<SingleNews key={i} img={el.img} />);
    });
    return (
      <section className="news-wrapper">
          {news}
      </section>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: ''
        }
    }
    mapObject(object, callback) {
      return Object.keys(object).map(function (key) {
        return callback(key, object[key]);
      });
    }
    componentDidMount () {
      const newsfeedURL = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/streetlife-coding-challenge/newsfeed.json';
      $.get(newsfeedURL, function(result) {
        this.setState({data: JSON.parse(result)});
        console.log(typeof this.state.data.messages);
      }.bind(this));
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {Object.keys(this.state.data.messages).map(function(key) {
                    return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.state.data.messages[key]}</div>;
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDom.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I am trying ti iterate over "this.state.data.messages" to output some data inside the render method.

After typing this "console.log(typeof this.state.data.messages);" I have gathered that "this.state.data.messages" is an object hence the following:

```
            {Object.keys(this.state.data.messages).map(function(key) {
                return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.state.data.messages[key]}</div>;
            })}
```

however I have the following inside my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Is `this.state.data.messages === null`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is you are initially setting data as an empty string. In your `componentDidMount` you are making the ajax call and since it's async react will still render. Once it renders it's trying to access `this.state.data.messages` which `this.state.data` is an empty string so will have no property called messages.

What I would do is have an initial state property called loading and in your render method if `this.state.loading === true` render something else in the div and if `this.state.loading === false && this.state.data.messages` actually return what your trying to do now.

Just make sure to set state of loading to false when you parse the JSON response

```
this.state = {
   data: '',
   loading: true
}
componentDidMount () {
    const newsfeedURL = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/streetlife-coding-challenge/newsfeed.json';
    $.get(newsfeedURL, function(result) {
        this.setState({
          data: JSON.parse(result),
          loading: false
        });
        console.log(typeof this.state.data.messages);
    }.bind(this));
}
render () {
  let content;
  if (this.state.loading === false && this.state.data.messages) {
    content = {Object.keys(this.state.data.messages).map(function(key) {
      return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.state.data.messages[key]}</div>;
    })}
  } else { 
    content = ''; // whatever you want it to be while waiting for data
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {content}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going to be rendering before that async call returns.

You need to handle the case before there's data. If nothing else you should change the initial state to better match the state you're expecting.